# Event receiver on user log in

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, event-receivers, rest

I'm trying to make a feature to assist with user provisioning.

Our users don't exist in our domain until they register, at which point they're sent directly to SharePoint.  I'm trying to populate their user profile either on account creation (the server that registers accounts to AD isn't in the SP farm, so I can't interface directly with the object model there).

Is there an event receiver for when a user first logs into a site? I was considering using webservices but I can't see a REST api call for creating a user profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API for the user profile service is read only. What I would suggest is that your registration app create an entry in a list with the required details and then you use an event receiver on that list to build the profile for the user.

Comment: That's a great idea. I'll give that a try

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: I'm glad it did!